# Valueerror: ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (178, 7) instead

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, roc, auc

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBy1V.png)

I keep getting an error here
i need to  measure how your model results change when using different test sets. To do that, simply start over the process at least 10 times with different splits of the full dataset into training and test

Comment: Please paste your code into this question rather than having a link and the full error. Also, could you provide a reference to the 'split_df' function you are using? I think you are likely naming the outputs of that function incorrectly and thus passing X_test rather than Y_train, which is why the shapes are wrong

Comment: Post split_df function and df.head()